# Microsoft Query TO_CHAR date

Tags: t-sql, microsoft-query

I'm trying to write sql select in Excel using Microsoft Query.
the problem is it produces error when trying to execute to_char(date, 'mm-dd-yyyy') ; I tried all the possible variations: to_char(date, `mm-dd-yyyy`) , to_char(date, "mm-dd-yyyy") , to_char(date, `'mm-dd-yyyy'`) .
Does anyone know symbols do I have to use to put the date format in??

Comment: I'm not sure that `TO_CHAR` is a T SQL function.

Comment: I tried cast(date as nvarchar(20)) too. unfortunately it makes the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to_char` is not a part of T-SQL, it's a part of PL/SQL.
The closest T-SQL equivalent is `format`, available from SQL-Server version 2012, and according to my [current search](https://www.google.co.il/search?rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&ei=yfVqWqaSKoHuUP-Cn4gC&q=ms%20query%20convert%20date%20to%20string&oq=MS%20Query%20date%20to%20string&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i22i30k1l6.7213.9178.0.11593.11.10.0.0.0.0.145.980.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.7.975...0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.0wNXi7eovC8) it's also available in MS query.

So instead of `to_char(date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')` use `format(date, 'MM-dd-yyyy')`

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: @GGSandro Just found and fixed a typo in my answer - format strings are case sensitive - `mm` stands for minutes, you need `MM` for months.

Comment: Well I guess that's probably different in MS query, then. In SQL Server it's case sensitive.